# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in joomla2.5

Tags: php, joomla

i am creating a joomla2.5 module.
I want to retrieve the data pass through parameter from the module, but am getting the about title error. Below is my code:
helper.php

```
class modFeedGrabber
{
    function feedurl(){
        $url = $params->get('feedUrl');
        return $url;
    }
    function maxCount(){
        $maxcount = $params->get('maxCount');
        return $maxcount;
    }
    function showDesc(){
        return $params->get('showDesc');
    }
    function showPubDate(){
        return $params->get('showPubDate');
    }
    function targetLink(){
        return $params->get('titleLinkTarget');
    }
    function descChar(){
        return $params->get('descCharacterLimit');
    }
    function fx(){
        return $params->get('fx');
    }
    function delay(){
        return $params->get('delay');
    }
    function timeout(){
        return $params->get('timeout');
    }
    function module_sfx(){
        return $params->get('moduleclass_sfx');
    }
}
```

mod_feedGrabber.php

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

$sitebase = JPATH_BASE;
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();

// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).DS.'/helper.php' );
$feed = new modFeedGrabber();
$url = $feed->feedurl($url);
$maxcount = $feed->maxcount($maxcount);
require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_feedGrabber' ) );
```

My new quetion is how can i get data pass from the module?

Comment: nowhere are you defining `$url` in your code, so you're effectively pasing a `null` value in to your methods.

Comment: $url is defined and assigned value in the method function feedurl()

Comment: @user1230116 - that method is expecting a parameter, and you're passing in `$url`, which is underfined. It's then looking to use that undefined paramater's `get` method, which is why you're getting an error.

Comment: no. it's not. it's being DEFINED by the return of the method call you're passing $url into. the `feeurl($url)` is what's causing the problem. you don't define it until AFTER the method call returns, but are trying to use it as part of the method call.

Comment: okay, i understand i have remove the $params, but how can i get the value passed as parameter by the module @MarcB

Comment: I answered your other question about this same problem here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958043/how-to-get-data-from-a-module-parameter-in-joomla

Comment: The question is not answer yet, you just point out an error @cppl

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comments above:

```
$url = $feed->feedurl($url);
                      ^^^^---- $url is not defined at this point
```

doesn't matter if feedurl() returns a $url value. At the time you **CALL** feedurl(), the `$url` you're trying to pass into the method is undefined. SO within feedurl(), you're doing

```
$url = $params->get(...);
       ^^^^^^^---the $url you passed in to the method, which is null/undefined
```

Then, of course, there's other problems:

```
    $url = $params->get(feedUrl);
                        ^^^^^^^--- undefined constant
```

Comment: How do i get data pass from the module interface created from the xml